# Working out the Oracle Select Statement

Tags: oracle, select

what im trying to do is to find number of saving account at each branch, and display the number and branch address.
here is code :

```
create type address as object 
 (
    street varchar2(20),
    city varchar2(10),
    p_code varchar2(8)
);

create type Branch as object
(
    BId varchar2(3),--branch id
    brAddress address,
    bPhone int
);

create table tb_Branch of Branch
（
    bid primary key   
）;

create type account as object
(
    accNum varchar2(4), --pk 
    accType varchar2(8), -- check(current, saving)
    balance number(8,2)
    BId_ref ref BId
);

create tb_account of account
(
    accNum primary key,
    constraint accType_const check(accType IN ('current','savings'))
);`
```

Please help!
thanks!

Comment: What problem are you having? You've shown some object creation DDL but no data, expected results or your attempt at a query. (Your DDL also seems to have some non-standard parentheses, missing commas and missing keywords...)

Comment: What have you tried so far????

Comment: i have create table and inserted the 20 data to each table, now i want find the number of saving account at each branch, and display the number and branch address thx

Comment: And how have you tried to solve the problem? It won't help you learn much if we do your homework for you, without you making any effort to do it yourself.

Comment: i tried so many times, i cant figure out by my self ,

Comment: i tried select b.address,count(*) 
from tb_account a join tb_branch b on a.bid=b.bid
where a.accType = savings

Comment: what you're looking for is `group by`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the following example (Oracle 12c) will help you to find a solution ... (the TYPEs and TABLEs may need tweaking).

**Types and tables**

```
-- types
create type address_t as object (
  street varchar2(20)
, city varchar2(10)
, postcode varchar2(8)
)
/

create type branch_t as object (
  brid varchar2(64)
, braddress address_t
, brphone varchar2(24)
)
/

create type account_t as object (
  accnum varchar2(4)
, acctype varchar2(8)
, balance number(12,2)
)
/

-- tables
create table branches （
  branch branch_t
, constraint branch_pk primary key ( branch.brid )
）;

create table accounts (
  id number generated always as identity primary key
, account_details account_t
, constraint acc_type_check check(
     account_details.acctype in ('current','savings')
  )
, branchid references branches( branch.brid )
);
```

**Some INSERTs (table BRANCHES)**

```
insert into branches ( branch )
  values ( 
    branch_t( '66-20-67'
             , address_t( '1 High St', 'Edinburgh', 'EH1 1AA' )
             , '00441155700340' ) 
    ) ;

-- trying to insert this again
-- gives us
-- ORA-00001: unique constraint (...BRANCH_PK) violated -> PK constraint working

insert into branches ( branch )
  values ( 
    branch_t( '88-45-13'
             , address_t( '2 Princes St', 'Edinburgh', 'EH2 2BB' )
             , '00441156800900' ) 
    ) ;

-- The BRANCHES table contains:
SQL> select * from branches;

BRANCH(BRID, BRADDRESS(STREET, CITY, POSTCODE), BRPHONE)                                                                   
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
BRANCH_T('66-20-67', ADDRESS_T('1 High St', 'Edinburgh', 'EH1 1AA'), '00441155700340')                                     
BRANCH_T('88-45-13', ADDRESS_T('2 Princes St', 'Edinburgh', 'EH2 2BB'), '00441156800900')
```

**Populate the ACCOUNTS table**

```
begin
  insert into accounts ( account_details, branchid )
  values ( account_t ( '7890', 'savings', 123456.78 ), '66-20-67' ) ;

  insert into accounts ( account_details, branchid )
  values ( account_t ( '7891', 'savings', 222222.22 ), '66-20-67' ) ;

  insert into accounts ( account_details, branchid )
  values ( account_t ( '7892', 'savings', 333333.33 ), '88-45-13' ) ;

  insert into accounts ( account_details, branchid )
  values ( account_t ( '6789', 'current', 234567.89 ), '88-45-13' ) ;
end;
/

-- fails due to CHECK constraint
insert into accounts ( account_details, branchid )
  values ( account_t ( '1234', 'standard', 4567.89 ), '66-20-67'  ) ;

-- ORA-02290: check constraint (...ACC_TYPE_CHECK) violated
```

**Query**

```
 /*
  from your question:
  " what im trying to do is 
    to find number of saving account at each branch,  
    and display the number and branch address "
*/  

-- suggested query
select 
  A.account_details.acctype  as acctype
, B.branch.brid              as branchid
, B.branch.braddress.city    as city
, count( * )
from branches B
  join accounts A on B.branch.brid = A.branchid
where A.account_details.acctype = 'savings' 
group by A.account_details.acctype
  , B.branch.brid
  , B.branch.braddress.city ;

ACCTYPE  BRANCHID   CITY         COUNT(*)
-------- ---------- ---------- ----------
savings  88-45-13   Edinburgh           1
savings  66-20-67   Edinburgh           2
```